# Using 'expect' to automatically send in password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, expect

I am trying to copy a file from my remote server to my local. Here's my script to run it, by using 'expect' to automaticlally send in password

```
scp user@host:/folder/myFile ./
expect "Password: "
send "myPassword"
```

When I run this, it still prompts for "Password", what is wrong?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

From what you are trying to do it sounds like you might be better off using ssh with a public and private key. You could google for ssh-keygen tutorial to get started.

Answer (score 14):

This expect script does the job (thanks to ['zedwood'](http://www.zedwood.com/article/142/linux-scp-expect-script) )

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set filename [lindex $argv 0]
set timeout -1
spawn scp $filename myusername@192.168.1.123:/home/myusername/
set pass "mypassword"
expect {
        password: {send "$pass\r" ; exp_continue}
        eof exit
}
```

Comment: The first working script I find on stackoverflow! Thank you for sharing! I always stumble on advices that I should not use expect in this way... Actually I was developing a program which I should tested on a router whose sshd server doesn't support public key authentification Orz. Using expect is my only salvation.

Answer (score 12):

While I agree with Sam and nik, the answer to you questions is that you didn't "hit enter":

```
send "mypassword\r"
```

Answer (score 4):

Please do not even leave such scripts around that might be picked up by someone else and used elsewhere… Try [public key authentication](https://web.archive.org/web/20081218032925/https://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/Public-Key_Authentication-2.html) instead, it is are very easy to setup.